# Why does ed start at the last line?

Tags: ed, historical-unix

Why does ed start at the last instead of first line of a file?

Most of ed's behavior makes sense when you remember that it was for interacting with a printer, but not this. Since I believe it reads the whole file into memory, it's not even an IO seek thing.

Comment: When reading a file, a natural counter would end up on the last line. I imagine that's a useful default, since the first line is always line 1. Don't know if the "why" is documented, off-hand.

Comment: Well, it landed in the spec, but that's probably documentation of  existing behavior. "If the edit buffer is not empty, the initial value for the current line shall be the last line in the edit buffer; otherwise, zero." From https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html

Comment: Following your concept of "interacting with a printer": what has already been printed must be above, what is going to be printed should start at this end point. Maybe?

Comment: Origin will likely need to be looked for in [QED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QED_(text_editor)) or possibly earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, after running any command in Ed, the cursor (i.e. the current line) is placed on the last line that was affected by the command. When ed starts and loads a file, that's equivalent to the `e` command. The `e` command affects the whole buffer, so it sets the current line to the last line.

Having the cursor end up on the last line is the most useful thing to do after inserting or loading text: typically, the next thing the user will do is to write more text after that. So, in fact, it's not that loading a file follows the general rule which happens to be to put the cursor at the end, but that loading a file justifies the general rule which is to put the cursor at the end.

Modern editors either put the cursor at the beginning or remember the last position. Ed isn't advanced enough to remember the last position. Putting the cursor at the beginning makes sense if the user is going to do some kind of global editing operation on the file, but not if the user is going to continue writing where they left off: this is most likely to happen at the end. Ed privileges the simplest operation (continue writing) over more complex operations, which is good user interface design.

Ex keeps this behavior. I don't know why Vi switched to put the cursor at the beginning of the file initially.

Comment: Also note that if the current line was the first one, a search would start searching from the second line (less of a problem for a `vi`sual editor I guess). (I have a vague recollection that it's at least part of the reason for the default position to be on the last line)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Whatever the rationale was, [Qed](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/qedman.html) was already setting the current line (".") to the last line read or added, although the 1970 Bell Labs documentation doesn't mention this as a design principle, unlike the [1973 ed manual](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V3/man/man1/ed.1) which states “Generally speaking, the current line is the last line affected by a command”.